# How do I compare the size of executeables in VB6?

Tags: vb6, comparison, filestream

I have a project where I need to compare 2 executeable files and see if they are of the same file size.

Unfortunately, this is an addition to an existing VB6 project. I'm not entirely sure how to do it other than compare filestreams?

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to recall that

```
FileLen(filename)
```

returns the file size

Comment: +1. Just like it says in the manual. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262742(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use FileLen() function - It returns size of file.

Answer (score 1):

Just one unrelated note on FileLen() - it completely and utterly fails on files over 4GB (e.g. greater than 32-bit integer).  Gotta use the Windows API to see the length of files that large.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileLen() as described in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w42d6ta5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I hope it fits better in the q&a philosophy now.